# Menu item selection issue on Mac OS

Tags: osx

I've noticed an annoying behavior in my installation of emacs on my Mac.  If the emacs window has the focus and I want to select something from the menu bar at the top of the screen (which says 'Emacs', by the way), I actually have to click the menu twice to get it to pull down.  It's as if the first click shifts focus to the menu bar and the second one selects the particular menu item.

I tried updating my emacs version, but that didn't help.  I now have 26.3.

Does anyone have a fix for this behavior?

Comment: Poor behavior with the menubar goes back in time at least to Emacs 24 on OSX  Snow Leopard ... I would imagine there is an open bug report, but I haven't searched.  This is not something that can be fixed with an answer in this particular forum as it is an internal bug ....  Perhaps [?] the Mac port maintained by Mitsuharu Yamamoto has some improvements/fixes for the behavior you describe:  https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/src/master/  After the first couple of months of using Emacs several years ago, I have just hid the menubar and increased the frame size to full screen pixel width.

Comment: The OSX/MacOS maintainer for the generic/vanilla version of the Emacs port (Alan Third) is a regular over at the reddit / Emacs tag.  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/  When posting to reddit, there is an option to post a link -- I would suggest posting a link on reddit to your question in this thread -- perhaps Alan will read it.  If not, you could also search the open bug reports and if there is not one already, file a new bug report.  `M-x report-emacs-bug`.